# Good practice when manipulating HTML controls via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

What is a good way to manipulating HTML controls?

By creating HTML element?

```
var select = document.getElementById("MyList");
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.Text = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    el.innerHTML = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}
```

Or by manipulating HTML:

```
    var options = new Array(2);
    options [0] = '1';
    options [1] = '2';

    options [0] = '<option>' + options [0] + '</option>';
    options [1] = '<option>' + options [1] + '</option>';

    var newHTML = '<select>' + options [0] + options [1] + '</select>';
    selectList.innerHTML = newHTML;
```

Which one of these is a good practice? Is one preferred over other in specific conditions?

Comment: Will that help:- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404083.aspx ?

Comment: It depends. What specific problem are you trying to solve? Most times one would want to define the control in html, so the second alternative would seem more suitable, but without knowing what you're trying to do one can't be 100% sure.

Comment: Not to be a debbie downer but I feel this question is primarily opinion-based

Comment: @Renan yes, I think it comes down to whether you want to define the control in html or not. When should one prefer defining the control in HTML?

Comment: @Dom as long as we don't know the specifics about the problem OP is trying to solve, I agree with you.

Comment: it depends on what you're doing. if it's a small project, it doesn't really matter. if you're designing a larger project or web app: neither. use a framework like angularjs and do it all in javascript without touching the dom.

Comment: Seems that using innerHTML is faster http://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-createelement-test

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Is it better to use innerHTML or (lots of) createElement calls to add a complex div structure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737307/javascript-is-it-better-to-use-innerhtml-or-lots-of-createelement-calls-to-ad)

Comment: Great answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7393126/361684

Comment: @user793468 first method is better .. it is much smoother.. see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always 1st approach. if you are using innerhtml style, browser is creating itself.

Comment: Arnt we creating browser by approach 1 too? "el.innerHTML = opt;"

Comment: Sorry i didn't see. you don't need el.innerHTML = opt;  el.Text = opt; change to el.text = opt;

Comment: Dont see the options in list if I remove el.innerHTML

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CbQ94/

Comment: Works in Chrome, not in IE. Tried deleting cookies but still doesnt work. Seems like an isolated issue. Will look into it more

Answer (score 4):

1st approach looks more modular and reusable. You may want to put the lines within for loop in a method and call that method.

Comment: I can always make the 2nd approach more modular and reusable. Thanks! for the info

Comment: @user793468 you need to consider other things too .. not just modularity ... let me know if i can improve the my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first method is better than the second one , i.e.,

**Creating an HTML element is better than manipulating the DOM"

**The reason:** being ***working with DOM can cause browser reflow.***

For example : assume you need to replace an element to the DOM which already exists.

Using approach :

1. **Creating a DOM Element** : You create an element. Add verious attributes to it and replace it. ***The element will be added in one go and there will be only one reflow of the document**.*
2. **Manipulating DOM** : You need to add and remove attributes or elements one by one. This ***may*** cause the browser to trigger a reflow for all the elements and attributes that are being manipulated. ***This will take up  valuable resources in rendering the flow of the document as the elements are manipulated**.*

So creating a dom element is much smoother since your browser wont have to render the flow of the document again.

***EDIT : *** If you need to insert ***many*** elements then the best approach is to [create a Document Fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment). The document fragment is in memory and not part of the DOM tree. Thus adding elements to it **DOES NOT** cause reflows. As the documentations says :

> Since the document fragment is in memory and not part of the main DOM tree, appending children to it does not cause page reflow (computation of element's position and geometry). Consequently, using document fragments often results in better performance.