# setAttribute not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, setattribute

I am making a plugin for form validation as practice, but for some reason after I create a h2 element and try to set it's attribute, it is not working. Here is the code

```
    var testing = function(regex, value, error_msg, error_msg_field_id){
        var pattern = new RegExp(regex);
        if (!pattern.test(value)){
            var ele = document.createElement("H2");
            var node = document.createTextNode(error_msg);
            ele.setAttribute('style', 'color:white');
            alert("hi");
            jQuery(error_msg_field_id).append(node);
        }
    }
```

the text appears with no problem, but it is not in white color. This make no sense at all to me

Comment: `ele.style.color = white;`?

Comment: yea I tried that too, but didnt work, it doesnt even alert(hi)

Comment: then your conditional statement is most likely not firing.

Comment: BTW, just a recommendation: use `console.log` instead of `alert` (unless you check your code in IE).

Comment: @Ohgodwhy no it is firing, it only doesnt alert(hi) if i change it to `ele.style.color=white`

Comment: @user308553 Where did you attach `ele`? you crated the element but didn't attach it to the document.

Comment: @Roy thanks for the suggestion, it does sound more useful after reading about it, I always thought it is the same as alert

Comment: @Roy omg... crap I am so sorry this is so embarassing, I missed that completely, I attached the node to the class instead. Thank you so much

Comment: Why didn't you use `innerHTML` instead of `createTextNode` and `jQuery.append`? It's faster.

Comment: @SuperScript, o seriously? I thought it is the same, Thanks!!! I will change it

Comment: @SuperScript, in general, innerHtml is slower(e.g [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11854965/196489)) than creating and appending elements. And when you simply want to change text, `textContent` is an excellent alternative as you also remove any unwanted insertion of HTML.

Comment: @user308553, I re-checked on my own, and I was way wrong.  `createTextNode` is _way_ faster than `innerHTML` or `textContent`! Thanks, @Tobo. Sorry for the misinformation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute) correctly, but you are setting the property on your h2-element, which is *never actually inserted* in your DOM.

You can change and simplify the relevant section of your code to:

```
var ele = document.createElement("H2");
ele.textContent = error_msg;
ele.setAttribute('style', 'color:white');
jQuery(error_msg_field_id).append(ele);
```

The usage of **jQuery** here is also not necessary. You can simply use

```
document.querySelector("#" + error_msg_field_id).appendChild(ele);
```

which is equally simple.

Comment: Hi, is there a advantage in using that instead of jQuery?

Comment: 1. You don't need jQuery ;) That means you could get around including a library of almost 100k.  
2. Using native javascript is almost certainly faster than going through jQuery. 3. You can feel good, because you used native javascript for something that others turn to libraries.

Comment: The only time you are in trouble is when using IE7 or below, as these don't know [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelector)

Comment: Thanks!! this is why I love this site so much. So many great teachers