# Else condition won't run

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I know the title is very annoying but anyways I start my question. I have created a function in a class that's kinda a multi-purpose one. I gave it a parameter which is of boolean type and of course only accepts "true" and "false" as values. Next, I am calling out that function through another PHP file on which the data is posted through ajax and that ajax is called through a button on my HTML page. Let me demonstrate it as a diagram:

[image: flow chart showing my program flow]

I hope you've understood my program flow, now let's come to the code or in other words here is what I've tried:

**HTML Page's button:**

```
document.write('<span class="pull-right" style="margin-top: -30px; margin-right: 20px;"><button id="accept_offer" class="btn btn-success" onclick="setPostOfferAcceptance(32);">Accept Offer</button></span>');
```

**AJAX Page:**

```
<?php

require_once '../../Classes/MyClass.php';

$offer_id = $_POST["id"];
$acceptance = $_POST["acceptance"];

$accepted = MyClass::SetOfferAcceptance($offer_id, $acceptance);

if($accepted) $data["status"] = "success";
else $data["status"] = "error";

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

**MyClass's Function:**

```
public static function SetOfferAcceptance($offerId, $acceptance) {
    if(Utilities::IsValid($offerId) && Utilities::IsValid($acceptance)) {
        Database::OpenConnection();

        $offerId = Utilities::SafeString(Database::$databaseConnection, $offerId);
        $acceptance = Utilities::SafeString(Database::$databaseConnection, $acceptance);

        $query = "";
        if($acceptance == true) {
            $query = Database::$databaseConnection->prepare("UPDATE post_offer SET Accepted=1 WHERE Offer_ID = ?");
        } else {
            $query = Database::$databaseConnection->prepare("UPDATE post_offer SET Accepted=0 WHERE Offer_ID = ?");
        }

        $query->bind_param("i", $offerId);
        $result = $query->execute();
        Database::CloseConnection();
        if($result) return 1; else return -1;
    }
}
```

And sorry, but finally, here's my javascript function that posts the data to the AJAX page:

```
function setPostOfferAcceptance(offer_id) {
    if($("#accept_offer").text() == "Accept Offer") {
        $.post("admin/post_offer/set_post_offer_acceptance.php", {id: offer_id, acceptance: true}, function(data){
            if(data.status == "success") {
                $("#acceptedOfferModal").modal("show");
                setTimeout(function(){ $("#acceptedOfferModal").modal("hide"); }, 2500);
                $("#accept_offer").text("Unaccept Offer");
                console.log(data.status);
            }
        }, 'json');
    } else if($("#accept_offer").text() == "Unaccept Offer") {
        $.post("admin/post_offer/set_post_offer_acceptance.php", {id: offer_id, acceptance: false}, function(data){
            if(data.status == "success") {
                $("#unacceptedOfferModal").modal("show");
                setTimeout(function(){ $("#unacceptedOfferModal").modal("hide"); }, 2500);
                $("#accept_offer").text("Accept Offer");
                console.log(data.status);
            }
        }, 'json');
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I forgot to post the JS code. But I've updated it now. Please consider it. Thanks.

The problem is that the function `SetOfferAcceptance()` is never running the else condition which is that if `$acceptance` is not equal to `true`.

Why? Can anyone please point out my mistake.

Thanks.

Comment: is acceptance ever false?

Comment: [Don't use `document.write`!](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/apis-in-html-documents.html#document.write)

Comment: @Oriol what should he use instead?

Comment: @user689 I know he would recommend me to use a templating engine.

Comment: @user1336827 I've posted my JS code which changes the value of acceptance.

Comment: @user689 For example, `document.getElementById('myElement').innerHTML = /* ... */`.

Comment: @Oriol It's really a bad practice to use `.innerHTML`

Comment: @user689 It's better than `document.write`. Of course `document.createElement`, `document.createTextNode`, `.appendChild`, etc. are safer (since HTML injection is not possible), but they don't provide the same functionality than `document.write`.

Comment: @Oriol Using a [library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737307/javascript-is-it-better-to-use-innerhtml-or-lots-of-createelement-calls-to-ad) would. However I was just pointing that the next time when you say "*Don't use ...*". Provide an alternative!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `acceptance` is boolean then use the following `if...else`, i.e. with tripple equals `$acceptance === true`:

```
// In AJAX page
if ($acceptance === true) {
  $query = Database::$databaseConnection->prepare("UPDATE post_offer SET Accepted=1 WHERE Offer_ID = ?");
} else {
  $query = Database::$databaseConnection->prepare("UPDATE post_offer SET Accepted=0 WHERE Offer_ID = ?");
}
```

Please reference: "[How do the equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comparis)"

**Update:**

Either check for `$acceptance` value in `SetOfferAcceptace`, or pass in `boolean` value to `SetOfferAcceptance`. Example with latter:

```
$offer_id = $_POST["id"];
$acceptance = false;
if (isset($_POST["acceptance"]) && $_POST["acceptance"] == 'accepted') {
  $acceptance = true;
}

$accepted = MyClass::SetOfferAcceptance($offer_id, $acceptance);
```

Comment: Thanks, but now only the second condition is running :/ It's never making it true.

Comment: @Arian Then only the first condition runs. :/

Comment: Aren't all post values string by default? Using a type sensitive comparison would never be `===` true.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui, can you post the value of `$_POST['acceptance']`?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn, yes.  The part I missed and paid the price for :(

Comment: @vee Then any alternative? :/

Comment: In your ajax page, I'd check for `acceptance` and pass a boolean instead of the actual value as the actual value is not used in your `SetOfferAcceptance` function.

Comment: Thanks, but I figured out an alternative that worked. Please check my answer if you want to know what it was. I just turned boolean into a string. :) I got that idea from @JonathanKuhn.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui, I added an alternative solution.

Comment: @vee Thanks again, but that's of no use because I know that `$acceptance` have a value when it comes to the page.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui, that's fine.  Yes `$acceptance` has a value which is why only `if` was executing before as all valid strings evaluate to true.  I added the `isset` check for safety, the check `$acceptance == 'accepted'` is what should make `$accepted` true.

Comment: But according to my previous code, I didn't set the value of `acceptance` to a string it was a boolean so is your alternative related to my previous code or the new one?

Comment: The `accepted` literal is based on your new code.  Basically what I'm trying to show is you can check for posted values and change boolean `@accepted` to either true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all for your answers but I figured out another alternative. That was instead of making `$acceptance` a boolean I made it a string and converted my JS code into:

```
function setPostOfferAcceptance(offer_id) {
    if($("#accept_offer").text() == "Accept Offer") {
        $.post("admin/post_offer/set_post_offer_acceptance.php", {id: offer_id, acceptance: "accepted"}, function(data){
            if(data.status == "success") {
                $("#acceptedOfferModal").modal("show");
                setTimeout(function(){ $("#acceptedOfferModal").modal("hide"); }, 2500);
                $("#accept_offer").text("Unaccept Offer");
                console.log(data.status);
            }
        }, 'json');
    } else if($("#accept_offer").text() == "Unaccept Offer") {
        $.post("admin/post_offer/set_post_offer_acceptance.php", {id: offer_id, acceptance: "unaccepted"}, function(data){
            if(data.status == "success") {
                $("#unacceptedOfferModal").modal("show");
                setTimeout(function(){ $("#unacceptedOfferModal").modal("hide"); }, 2500);
                $("#accept_offer").text("Accept Offer");
                console.log(data.status);
            }
        }, 'json');
    }
}
```

And my class's function into:

```
public static function SetOfferAcceptance($offerId, $acceptance) {
    if(Utilities::IsValid($offerId) && Utilities::IsValid($acceptance)) {
        Database::OpenConnection();

        $offerId = Utilities::SafeString(Database::$databaseConnection, $offerId);
        $acceptance = Utilities::SafeString(Database::$databaseConnection, $acceptance);

        $query = "";
        if($acceptance == "accepted") {
            $query = Database::$databaseConnection->prepare("UPDATE post_offer SET Accepted=1 WHERE Offer_ID = ?");
        } else {
            $query = Database::$databaseConnection->prepare("UPDATE post_offer SET Accepted=0 WHERE Offer_ID = ?");
        }

        $query->bind_param("i", $offerId);
        $result = $query->execute();
        Database::CloseConnection();
        if($result) return 1; else return -1;
    }
}
```

And that worked! :)

Thanks again *@vee*.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken your issue stems from automatic type casting.

```
if($result) return 1; else return -1; // both of these evaluate to boolean true because -1 is an integer

if($result) return 1; else return 0; // evaluates to true/false respectively

if($result) return true; else return false; // evaluates to true/false respectively
```

The last line is what you should honestly be using.

Comment: Thanks, but that answer is not related to my question and there's a reason behing why I used `1` and `-1`.

Comment: Well I just hope this issue doesn't bite you in the butt because the `if($accepted)` block will ALWAYS evaluate to "success" the way it is currently written.