# Setting .innerHTML on a newly created TD element blank when content is returned from a function

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml

In short, why does the following function work where the latter function does not?

**Working Code**

```
function createRawRowElementViaInnnerHTML(){
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.innerHTML = '<td>'+createDropDownHTML()+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+createTxtAreaDownHTML()+'</td>';
  return row;
}
```

**Non-Working Code**

```
function createRowElement(){
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  var td1 = document.createElement("td");
  td1.innerHTML="Col 1 innerHTML -- should be overwritten";
  td1.innerHMTL=createDropDownHTML();
  var td2 = document.createElement("td");
  td2.innerHTML="Col 2 innerHTML -- should be overwritten";
  td2.innerHMTL=createTxtAreaDownHTML();
  row.appendChild(td1);
  row.appendChild(td2);
  return row;
}
```

I'd expect that creating the `<td>` elements and setting their `.innerHTML` would work the same as hard coding the table cell's inner html like such `'<td>'+createDropDownHTML()+'</td>'`. The "non-working code" produces the `<tr>` element with two `<td>` elements, but those `<td>` elements content are blank (*for demo purposes I set their innerHTML to show they were created correctly*). Behavior is observed on both FF32 and Chrome37.

Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54wfgv3b/1/) for the remaining code (such as the function calls). Also, I attempted to use the new stack overflow code-snippet, this is the same code that can be found on the fiddle.

```js
for(var i =0; i<5;i++){
    var r = createRowElement();
    document.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(r);
    var r2 = createRawRowElementViaInnnerHTML();
    document.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(r2);
}

function createRawRowElementViaInnnerHTML(){
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    row.innerHTML = '<td>'+createDropDownHTML()+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+createTxtAreaDownHTML()+'</td>';
    return row;
}
function createRowElement(){
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    var td1 = document.createElement("td");
    td1.innerHTML="Col 1 innerHTML -- should be overwritten";
    td1.innerHMTL=createDropDownHTML();
    var td2 = document.createElement("td");
    td2.innerHTML="Col 2 innerHTML -- should be overwritten";
    td2.innerHMTL=createTxtAreaDownHTML();
    row.appendChild(td1);
    row.appendChild(td2);
    return row;
}
function createDropDownHTML(){
    return '<select><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option></select>';
}
function createTxtAreaDownHTML(){
    return '<textarea></textarea>';
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable"></table>
```

Any Ideas? Most posts that came up from googling had to do with the dom not being ready, which isn't the case here. Also read a post about some form of potential html validation/clean-up, but I do not understand why it'd work one way and not the other since in both functions I am using `.innerHTML` on some level. Looking for an answer with documentation/resources as to why the latter function doesn't work. Thank you for your time.

Comment: `td1.innerHMTL=createDropDownHTML();`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737307/javascript-is-it-better-to-use-innerhtml-or-lots-of-createelement-calls-to-ad If I were you, I'd take that advice or stick with what already worked.  Good luck!

Comment: To anyone who stumbles across this question with the ability to cast close votes; This question should be closed because it is "a simple typographical error" (found under [Off Topic, number 2](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the help center).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function createRowElement(){
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  var td1 = document.createElement("td");
  td1.innerHTML="Col 1 innerHTML -- should be overwritten";
  td1.innerHMTL=createDropDownHTML();  // should be HTML instead of HMTL
  var td2 = document.createElement("td"); 
  td2.innerHTML="Col 2 innerHTML -- should be overwritten";
  td2.innerHMTL=createTxtAreaDownHTML(); // should be HTML instead of HMTL
  row.appendChild(td1);
  row.appendChild(td2);
  return row;
}
```

As seen in the above comments, you should change those lines to:

```
// ...
td1.innerHTML = createDropDownHTML();
// ...
td2.innerHTML = createTxtAreaDownHTML();
```

In these cases usually its a problem of spellings and cases. All you need to do is have a sharp eye. The M and the T in the HTML are switched in your code.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see the difference between your suggestion and what I have.

Comment: @ArtyMcFly Dude HMTL!=HTML (Change HMTL by HTML)

Comment: Thanks for your patience, stared at the code so long that HMTL and HTML looked the same to me!