# If people recommend I shouldn't use .innerHTML, what then should I instead use?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: Is it better to use innerHTML or (lots of) createElement calls to add a complex div structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737307/javascript-is-it-better-to-use-innerhtml-or-lots-of-createelement-calls-to-add)

What should I use instead of `.innerHTML`? All advice is appreciated.

Comment: Who recommends such a thing?

Comment: in what context? what are you trying to do?

Comment: why are they telling you not to use .innerHTML?

Comment: Prediction: the person who told you this uses jQuery and/or Dreamweaver. Accurate?

Comment: Why didn't nobody mention the possibility of XSS (Cross-Site Scripting) attacks?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The correct answer is that in certain situations you should use innerHTML, and in other situations you should use appendChild.  Here's when to use innerHTML or appendChild:

- Use innerHTML when you're setting text inside of an HTML tag like an anchor tag, paragraph tag, span, div, or textarea.
- Use appendChild() If you're trying to add new DOM elements inside of another DOM
  element.

Comment: *"The correct answer is that in certain situations you should use innerHTML..."* I don't think it's correct to say that you *"should"* use `innerHTML`, but it certainly is an option.

Comment: I actually do mean to say "should use".  String concatenation is more computationally expensive than working with DOM objects directly.  Therefore, it's good practice to use appendChild() to add new DOM objects, and it's good practice to use innerHTML when you're actually wanting to insert text.

Comment: Yes, but saying it's *"good practice"* to use `.innerHTML` to insert text is different than saying you *"should"* use `.innerHTML` for that. There's nothing wrong with using `document.createTextNode()` along with `.appendChild()` if you want some text inserted. But I do agree that it is good practice to use `appendChild()` and similar for DOM elements.

Comment: Actually, if you're just adding text, use `innerText`.

Comment: @YiddishNinja `innerText` is non-standard, however it is fairly widely supported: http://caniuse.com/#search=innerText

Comment: The more standards-compliant way to insert text is to append a text node.  The DOM API unfortunately makes this needlessly terse - why couldn't they have made `$element->appendChild('This text');` work instead of needing something like `$element->appendChild($doc->createTextNode('This text`));`?  At any rate, it avoids the problems of needing to escape '<' and '&' for innerHTML, and that innerText is non-standard (and treats whitespace weirdly).

Comment: Consider also that string concatenation to build HTML is also more error prone.

Comment: Actually, @thomasrutter, check out [element.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append). It accepts either a _node object_ or a _string_ as input, and can accept multiple nodes/string to append with one call.

Comment: @DavidMichaelGregg those new methods are quite useful - if only DOM had had that from the start we wouldn't have had to fudge around with any of this.  Note this question/answer harks from a time before those.

Comment: @thomasrutter For sure! It has been around _just_ long enough in the biggest browsers now that I recently started teaching it as the default way to add things to the DOM – along with `prepend()`, `after()`, and `before()` in vanilla JS.

Answer (score 3):

You can use W3C compliant methods, like:

- [`createElement()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.createElement)
- [`appendChild()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/AppendChild)
- [`removeChild()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/removechild)
- [`replaceChild()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/replacechild)
- [`insertBefore()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/insertbefore)
- [`createTextNode()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3adocument.createTextNode)

Comment: Actually `innerHTML` is perfectly W3C compliant as per the actual W3C docs here: https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Parsing/ "DOMParser, XMLSerializer, innerHTML, and similar APIs" and as per here, it is supported in all browsers including IE8+ http://caniuse.com/#search=innerHTML

Comment: `innerHTML` is fine in the cases that the answer specifies.

Comment: `.innerHTML` was indeed non-standard back in 2011. @jonlink: It can only be used consistently in place of `.appendChild()`, but to do that you need to use `+= new_data`, which can introduce bugs to your code.

Comment: I realize this answer is old, but since SO is a living doc it is worth mentioning. Just about everything was non-standard in 2011 :) In any case I was actually referring to using innerHTML to fill or replace contents as a whole, so `+= new data` would be unnecessary. That said, it isn't performant. For example if you want to empty the [innerHTML a while loop is better](https://coderwall.com/p/nygghw/don-t-use-innerhtml-to-empty-dom-elements)

Comment: EDIT: seems innerHTML was standard in 2011 ([source](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-innerHTML-not-standard-yet)). Maybe you were thinking of innerText?

Answer (score 3):

Without any context, there is only one rule: there are no rules.

There are no situations in programming where one follows some "rule" blindly, regardless of the context. If innerHTML were inherently eval, I mean evil, it wouldn't be in the language specification to begin with!

The alternatives to using innerHTML vary depending on what you are trying to do, what (if any) javascript libraries you have, and what (if any) browsers you are targeting.

When you're creating a new section of HTML, you can use `document.createElement` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.createElement)) to make each element, using `appendChild` and the like to add elements to one another. If you're changing the text of an element from "blue" to "red", you'd use `innerHTML` to accomplish that (assuming you don't use any of the popular javascript frameworks).

Answer (score 1):

When *practical*, it's better to create the DOM objects yourself and add them to the DOM tree—performance will be better. For complex elements, it's probably better to use `innerHTML` or otherwise you'll have unmaintainable code.

Answer (score 0):

Just like [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737307/javascript-is-it-better-to-use-innerhtml-or-lots-of-createelement-calls-to-add), "use an API".  [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) is way better at this than you and its extremely easy to use, so just use that.

Looks like no one wants to click through so i'll quote the answer.

> Neither. Use a library like jQuery, Prototype, Dojo or mooTools
>   because both of these methods are fraught with trouble:
>
> - [Did you know that innerHTML on tables for IE is readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155426/why-does-ie-give-unexpected-errors-when-setting-innerhtml)
> - [Did you know for the select element it's broken as well?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228)
> - [How about problems with createElement?](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/10/bug-235-createelement-is-broken-in-ie.html)
>
> The writers of the major javascript libraries have
>   spent a lot of time and have entire bug tracking systems to make sure
>   that when you call their DOM modifying tools they actually work.
>
> If you're writing a library to compete with the above tools (and good
>   luck to you if you are), then I'd choose the method based on
>   performance, and innerHTML has always won out in the past, and since
>   innerHTML is a native method, it's a safe bet it will remain the
>   fastest.

The key takeaway here is that DOM manipulation done right is a sufficiently complex task to really make one look strongly at using a library to abstract away the headaches you may encounter.

Comment: Discussion [moved to chat.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3597/discussion-between-allen-and-chris)

Comment: adding an entire library to avoid using innerHTML is a horrible suggestion

Answer (score -1):

You should exchange objects (JSON or XML) instead of pure HTML between AJAX requests. Then, you need a presentation logic on your client to handle the data (JSON or XML) and update the DOM accordingly.

Comment: I +1'd this because I agree, but I don't think he's asking this.  I think he's asking for things to do DOM manipulation with, like createElement, etc

Comment: What does this even have to do with the question?!