# javascript doesn't set the value of td tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm very new to JavaScript and I wish I could set the value of a `td` tag using JavaScript.

I have code like this to do so:

```
window.onload = function() {
     document.getElementById("units").value = "122"
}
```

And I have a html file like this:

```
<table class="table" width="100%">
    <caption class="bold">TNEB UnitCalculator</caption>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>testing</td>
            <td id="units"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But that doesn't seems to be working!

Comment: Do you want to set the attribute 'value' of the `td` or the text between the opening and closing tags?

Comment: What exactly is it you want to do? A TD doesn't have a value attribute.

Comment: Need to put the data between the opening and closing tags!

Comment: end your line with semicolon ";"

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823498/setting-innerhtml-vs-setting-value-with-javascript/8823546.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `td` tag doesn't have a value attribute:

```
document.getElementById("units").appendChild(document.createTextNode(122));
```

Or if you want to set some attribute:

```
document.getElementById("units").setAttribute('data-value', 122);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `td` element does not have a `value` attribute. Use `innerHTML` instead.

Comment: Didn't down vote, but `innerHTML` is the worst thing you can do in this situation.

Comment: Why is it? Using createTextNode is really only necessary in a few cases. For example, when you have a <span> in an element and want to append text not in any tag after that <span>

Comment: Not my -1, but I imagine it's because you're using `innerHTML` instead of DOM. Not that that's a valid reason to downvote imo, it works just fine. (although it might not be the best option)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476638/if-people-recommend-i-shouldnt-use-innerhtml-what-then-should-i-instead-use explains a lot more in detail

Comment: Getting or setting the content of a <td> with `innerHTML` is perfectly valid and has the desired result.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp `innerHTML` destroys the possible DOM elements as well as is slower.

Comment: @Cerbrus How `innerHTML` is _not_ part of the DOM??

Comment: @PeeHaa Yes it does _replace_ all elements but as long as this is your goal, it's perfectly OK.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp If you want to replace all elements in it you should still not use it. Because looping through the elements and removing them using DOM is waaay faster. There is a (limited) use case for `innerHTML`, but this just isn't it.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp: _"DOM - Document Object Model"_. There's nothing "Object-oriented" about `innerHTML`, it just uses a string. That's the problem with it. The browser has to re-parse the entire page if you use `innerHTML`, because the browser has no way of knowing what your object structure is, after inserting a string at a random position in your document.

Comment: I don't agree. Suppose you have a large number of DOM elements. Iterating through them and individually removing is more expensive and slower than doing it in one expression using `innerHTML`.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp: in that case, you could just remove and re-build the parent, possibly. Also, do you have any sources to back-up your claim that removing all children from an element is slower than setting it's `innerHTML`? **[Here's a JSperf I found](http://jsperf.com/empty-content-innerhtml-vs-dom/2)** about this. For 1000 child elements, DOM manipulation is between about 8 and 80 times as fast.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp You can disagree. But that is a moot point until you have tested it and came to the comclusion your statement is wrong.

Comment: @PeeHaa I doubt you are right in the performance difference. I'll pull up a quick test.

Comment: @PeeHaa Please see yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/QXuxL/ `innerHTML` ~ 10ms vs. iterating and removing elements ~100+ms. So how is it more efficient or fast if one does _not_ user the `innerHTML`? Interestingly, a very similar test to the one you linked yields different results. I'm open to any explanations.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp: I [took the liberty to edit your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QXuxL/9/). I added a load more TD's, and modified your DOM function, it was very inefficient.
Now, the `innerHTML` is only 3,5 times as fast for that many elements, compared to 10 times. The larger the sample data gets, the more DOM manipulation gains on innerHTML, untill ut's utterly smashed by DOM, as seen in @PeeHaa's example.

Comment: You are welcome! But is the `innerHTML` way still not the fastest?

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code is working correctly

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("units").value = "122"
    }
</script>

<table class="table" width="100%">
    <caption class="bold">TNEB UnitCalculator</caption>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>testing</td>
            <td id="units"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can check this in your browsers developer tools. In the command line, type:

```
document.getElementById("units").value
```

Comment: LOL, you're right, althought this can't be seen directly on the page : ).

Comment: this guy just playing with us..putting ever one down vote.pls close this question