# Is it true that document.getElementById().innerHTML can't be used to insert new html which would disrupt the bracketing it is inner to?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I've been mucking around with Javascript for the first time and have found that while you can easily do something like

```
<p id="demo"> Hello </p>

<script> document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<strong>Hello</strong>"; </script>
```

and get "**Hello**". You can't do something like

```
<p> Hello my name is <strong id="demo">Sam</strong></p>

<script> document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Sam </strong> and <strong> Susan"; </script>
```

and get "Hello my name is **Sam** and **Susan**".

I've had a look at places like w3schools to try to understand this. My best guess is that for whatever reasons .innerHTML can't actually change the "outer" of the element that it's altering. I'd love it if somebody could give me a slightly more clear explanation of this behaviour. I don't think it's something I want to use I'd just like to understand it a little better.

Comment: `innerHTML` the name itself says that it is referencing the inner part of that particular element.

Comment: Using innerHtml is never a good idea.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476638/if-people-recommend-i-shouldnt-use-innerhtml-what-then-should-i-instead-use

Comment: The DOM isn't a string. It doesn't have closing an opening tags. The HTML markup is discarded after the page loads. Any HTML manipulation you do via JS must be complete and valid representations, which then also will be discarded after they've been parsed into DOM elements.

Comment: Thanks all. What I wasn't understanding was the way HTML and documents were related. I thought it would insert the text into the innerHTML then reparse the whole thing.

Comment: That's a pretty common misconception. I don't mind a little `.innerHTML` insertion here and there when sensible, but try to avoid adding new content to existing content with `.innerHTML += "...new content..."`. There are much better, safer and more appropriate ways.

Comment: W3schools is a terrible resource. Use MDN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documents don't really work in term of HTML tags. As soon as parsing ends, there is no more HTML, only the DOM structure, which on demand can be translated back to HTML.

In your example the parser looks at the string `Sam </strong> and <strong> Susan`, sees that it's incomplete and tries to correct it, so you get `Sam and <strong> Susan</strong>`.

I suppose it could dump the DOM to HTML, replace the `innerHTML` literally and re-parse the whole thing, but that would be a lot slower with insignificant benefits.