# Unstoppable addEventListener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, addeventlistener

When I click on the link it's working perfectly but only ONCE.

I want to be able to be able to keep the `addEventListener` even after it's been executed.

```
<div id=myBox>
    <a href="#" id="append">append</a>
</div>
```

```js
document.getElementById("append").addEventListener("click", appendMore);
function appendMore() {
    myBox.innerHTML += '1';
}
```

Comment: You remove listener because a element is replaced by new HTML content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use a separate element to insert your content into.

```js
document.getElementById("append").addEventListener("click", appendMore);

function appendMore() {
  tgt.innerHTML += "1";
}
```

```html
<div id=myBox>
  <a href="#" id="append">append</a>
  <span id="tgt"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, do not use innerHTML. This causes so many bugs it's not worth it.

Comment: @Eraden So what's the alternative ?

Comment: `innerHTML` isn't inherently evil, but it has it's gotchas. Using it if you're aware of what you're doing has no downsides. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476638/if-people-recommend-i-shouldnt-use-innerhtml-what-then-should-i-instead-use) for further discussion, for example.

Comment: That's like saying we should use screwdrivers to hit nails because occasionally people hurt themselves with hammers.

Comment: @Nit - A more accurate analogy would be "If you're going to use a hammer, make sure you understand how it can hurt you, and get trained up before going full steam ahead"

Comment: If you say so you probably know what is the best. From my experience this is simply evil part of DOM like eval is evil part of JS. jQuery is simplest, most secure way but people downvote it, why?

Comment: @Eraden Because it's suggesting loading up an 85KB library for something that vanilla Javascript can do just as easily, with less clutter attached.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Parent element
var el = document.querySelector('#myBox');
// Find append and add listener
el.querySelector("#append").addEventListener("click",appendMore);

function appendMore( event ) {
    // Append new text node
    el.appendChild( document.createTextNode('1') );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It would be achieved easily by using jQuery.

```
$('#append').click(function () {
    $('#myBox').append('1');
});
```

find this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u58ytkar/)**

**NB:** Please let us know if you want to achieve this using just plain javascript.

Comment: I know how to do it with jQuery I asked about javascript

Comment: @davidmarko in defence of Sameer, you did tag the question with jQuery. I would suggest you edit your question to remove that tag if you don't want jQuery related answers.

Comment: ohh.. ok. I could not catch if from question. apologies.

Comment: ...and I thought it would be extremely simple