# Replacing document.documentElement.innerHTML in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, innerhtml

The following works flawlessly (as far as I can tell) in all other browsers:

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML = "<head></head><body>Testing</body>";
```

But chokes in IE (I tested IE9), with a console error:

```
SCRIPT600: Invalid target element for this operation.
```

...referencing the first character of the line of code above.

Why won't this work in IE, but will work in all other browsers? I read somewhere that `innerHTML` has issues replacing 'TBODY' elements, but I tested this line of code after removing all TBODY children and the same error occurred.

I know this sounds like bad-news-code, but it is the only option I have left with the very limited and simplistic CMS website we are being forced to use. I'm only thankful that the CMS allows scripts to be executed.

In essence, I need to be able to completely gut the HTML contents and use my own. Again, this works fine on other browsers.

Other notes:

- The CMS is using the `prototype.js` library (it's already loaded before I run this code)
- The Doctype is: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`
- The CMS scripts use `prototype.js` to dynamically add two `div`s full of content at page load

Comment: Is this true in my situation? http://stackoverflow.com/a/255180/435596 Will I never be able to change the contents of `HEAD` or `HTML` in IE?

Comment: Yes, you've found the correct answer; `innerHTML` is read-only even for `<html>` element in IE up to version 9. Anyway, I think it'll be better to replace `document.body.innerHTML` and `document.title` - these include all visible content and you won't experience any problems, without the need for rewriting whole `<head>` content.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I am using the BODY now, however my external links are not loading in the head and are causing problems, and the external resources the CMS is loading in the HEAD are also messing things up. Can I accept your comment as an answer? How should this be answered?

Answer (score 2):

```
document.open("text/html", "replace");
document.write("<head></head><body>Testing</body>");
document.close();
```

Comment: This method has one additional advantage over `document.documentElement.innerHTML` - it triggers all events like `body.onload` once again. Because of that, it's a better choice on newer browsers too.

Comment: doing this causes flicker

Answer (score 1):

As both @duri and I confirmed, the `documentElement` (`<html>`) object along with a handful of other certain HTML elements are read-only in Internet Explorer (see link in first comment), and therefore replacing the `documentElement` in a cross-browser fashion is not possible.

Using Javascript to strip all existing `link` and `script` tags from the `head`, then to set the `body` attributes to match the replacement content, then to replacing the `innerHTML` of the `body`, and finally dynamically adding my own `script`, `meta`, and `css` tags as children of the `head`, achieves nearly the same thing.

Thanks to @duri for the workaround tip!